JS why it says date is in range but it is not?
I have a array of blocked times
like this:
{
  "blockedTimes": [
    {"startTime": "1717228800", "endTime": "1719734400"},
    {"startTime": "1719820800", "endTime": "1722412800"},
    {"startTime": "1722499200", "endTime": "1725091200"},
    {"startTime": "1725177600", "endTime": "1727683200"},
    {"startTime": "1727769600", "endTime": "1730365200"},
    {"startTime": "1730451600", "endTime": "1732957200"},
    {"startTime": "1733043600", "endTime": "1735635600"},
    {"startTime": "1735722000", "endTime": "1738314000"},
    {"startTime": "1738400400", "endTime": "1740733200"},
    {"startTime": "1740819600", "endTime": "1743408000"},
    {"startTime": "1743517800", "endTime": "1746000000"},
    {"startTime": "1746086400", "endTime": "1748678400"},
    {"startTime": "1748764800", "endTime": "1751270400"},
    {"startTime": "1751356800", "endTime": "1753948800"},
    {"startTime": "1754035200", "endTime": "1756627200"},
    {"startTime": "1756713600", "endTime": "1759219200"},
    {"startTime": "1759305600", "endTime": "1761901200"},
    {"startTime": "1761987600", "endTime": "1764469800"},
    {"startTime": "1764579600", "endTime": "1767171600"},
    {"startTime": "1767258000", "endTime": "1769850000"}
  ]
}

then I have a starttime and endTime to check if the date is in range of the given array
function epochToJsDate(ts) {
  // ts = epoch timestamp
  // returns date obj
  return new Date(ts * 1000);
}

for (let bt = 0; bt < rs.data.blockedTimes.length; bt++) {
  const range = rs.data.blockedTimes[bt];
  const start = epochToJsDate(range.startTime).getTime()
  const end = epochToJsDate(range.endTime).getTime();
  const bstart = new Date(parseInt(d.booking_info.start_date)).getTime();
  const bend = new Date(parseInt(d.booking_info.end_date)).getTime();

  if ((bstart > start) && (end <= bend)) {
    console.log('IN range')
  } else {
    console.log('not')
  }
}

my start date is in 2029 and endtime also but it says it is in range but the ranges are all over 2025.
what I am doing wrong ?

Why are you bothering to convert the values to dates? Why not compare them as numbers?

You are checking this:
Start Date (2025) < Event Start Date 2029

End Date (2025) < Event End Date 2029

Both the above are true, and hence you log IN range
You should check for:
Start Date > Event Start Date 2029

and
End Date < Event Start Date 2029

So basically: ((bstart < start) && (end <= bend))
